# Decrypt Data on SqlDataSource Selecting

Tags: encryption, sqldatasource

I have a table which I store encrypted data in it.
I use sqldatasource to do the CRUD.
I need to decrypt whole data in selecting event of sqldatasource, like this:

```
protected void sqldatasource_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Columnname="col1")
        {
            MeyDecryptMethod."col1".ToString();
        }
    }
```

please tell me if it is possible to do it this way or not, and how.
Thanks

PS: please do not suggest other ways. because in this scenario only this method is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting event rise starting select, so you cannot access data in this event, event details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: thanks for your answer
can i do it on selected event of sqldatasource?

Comment: I don't know your app structure. If you use DTO, you can do same thing on while transferring data to class. If you are using EF, you can create db function for decrypting.